# PowerShell Write-EventLog Not Writing to Desired Event Log

Tags: .net, visual-studio, powershell

I have the below code (snippet) in a PowerShell function (named Create-EventLog). The end result should be the following:

- A new Event Log named `Get-Drives` were PowerShell writes all exception messages for this application. The `Get-Drives` event log gets created but for some reason
  the actual message(s) are only getting written in the default `Windows PowerShell` event log. How can I make PowerShell write the messages to the "Get-Drives" event log instead of the "Windows PowerShell" event log? I'm using PowerShell 4 and using PowerShell tools in Visual Studio 2013.

My PowerShell function snippet:

```
if (!$EventLogExists) {
    New-EventLog -LogName "Get-Drives" -source "Get-Drives"
    Write-EventLog -LogName "Get-Drives" -source "Get-Drives" -EventId 1 -message "There was an error"
    return
} else {
    Write-EventLog -LogName "Get-Drives" -source "Get-Drives" -EventId 1 -message "There was an error"
    return
}
```

Running `Get-EventLog -List` reveals the below output:

[image]

Under entries there is a value 1 for the `Get-Drives` log but it only displays in the Windows Powershell log which also has a value of 1.

Screenshot of the Event Viewer

Get-Drives log:
[image]

Windows Powershell log:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if your EventLog is created, this command will list all your events log's on local computer:

> Get-EventLog -list

If your EventLog is not in the list, try to create it by using just this command and not your function(run as administrator your PS console):

> New-EventLog -LogName "Get-Drives" -source "Get-Drives"

Then run again to see if your EventLog has been created.

> Get-EventLog -list

If your new EventLog present in the list then run your function to see if now he will be able to write in the right EventLog

Comment: I've updated my entry. Thanks. Also, even running it interactively produces the same issue. The event log gets created, just in the Windows Powershell log instead of the Get-Drives.

Comment: Very strange, it work perfectly on my win10. Can your please link you complete function?

Comment: Let me know if this link works (never used this site before): http://codeshare.io/Z2bmx

Comment: Nothing wrong, also work on my system. What is the OS version of your client? Fully patched?

Comment: Hmm....Windows 8.1, but on a VM I setup at home. Since it works on your system, I'll give a shot tomorrow at work. Thanks for everything.

Comment: Try also to give a static name for -LogName, I'm not sure but the issue can be related to the extension of the -LogName which is .ps1 in your print screen above(Get-Drives.ps1).

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem too; it seems to be an issue in EventViewer. I fixed it restarting **Windows Event Log** Service and recreating de EventSource.